# optimize search to reduce search time

Tags: java, database, oracle, search, optimization

my web site has a search function, user can search forum topic by typical word. I use oracle's database to store the topic. At very begin, we only have 200G data, now, we have 20T, user Complain that they have to wait too long to get the feedback. We already optimize the database's search function, and don't expect to squeeze any juice out of oracle. But HOW? What can I do now?

Comment: How did you optimize the db? I assume you're searching for a word occurring anywhere within a DB field? How did you escape a full-table scan?

Comment: it is a full text search?

Comment: what kind of query is it?

Comment: not sure if this is something you have explored/exploited already. but you might want to have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/overview.htm#i1007403

Comment: It's impossible to say how to optimize a DB, or even a single statement without knowing anything about that db. You should identify the statement to optimize and post it here, including the complete structure of all the involved tables, their number of rows and the actual behaviour.

Comment: we have optimized db search, we want to use other concept but not DB optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use some Index engine used only for searching task : ElasticSearch, Lucene, Solr, ...

Answer (score 0):

So you have x 100 more data than when you started.

Maybe you need a hardware upgrade?

Comment: hardware upgrade is an option, but this won't be a good solution,because it's efficiency in very short time.